# How to avoid serialization error when dynamically adding columns to dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, serialization

I am attempting to iterate over a list of column names containing columns to be ranked with a window function and to add a new column with the resulting top value of the source column. To do this, I declared the input dataframe as a variable outside of the for loop and update it within the loop. This results in `Task not serializable` which from my understanding is probably due to the fact that the varialbe df is declared on the master node and then the for loop is trying to access it on worker nodes. Can I avoid this error using the same logic, or is there a different way I should approach adding these columns?

```
 def getHighestScoredAttributes(scoredDF: DataFrame, attributes: Array[String]) : DataFrame = {
    var df = scoredDF
    for (attribute <- attributes) {
      val maxValidWindow = Window.partitionBy(df("druid")).orderBy(
        when(df("validity") === lit("valid"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)).desc,
        when(df(attribute).isNotNull, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)).desc,
        df("rank").desc_nulls_last)
      val maxInvalidWindow = Window.partitionBy(df("druid")).orderBy(
        when(df("validity") === lit("invalid"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)).desc,
        when(df(attribute).isNotNull, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)).desc,
        df("rank").desc_nulls_last)
      df = df.withColumn("valid_" + attribute, first(attribute) over maxValidWindow)
        .withColumn("valid_" + attribute + "_dt", first("attest_dt") over maxValidWindow)
        .withColumn("invalid_" + attribute, first(attribute) over maxInvalidWindow)
        .withColumn("invalid_" + attribute + "_dt", first("attest_dt") over maxInvalidWindow)
    }
    df
  }
```

Comment: Can you add stack trace of error and code how you call you `def`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was not with the code above, but with the rank column in the orderby. It is declared outside the scope of this function with a window function, but lazily evaluated within the function body, leading to this error. Marking that Window val with @transient resolve the issue.